# Reduce IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe a)) to IO (Maybe a)

Tags: haskell, monads, function-signature

I have a function that reads an Rsa key with the HsOpenSsl's `readPrivateKey` function unfortunately the signature of my function is this `String -> IO (Maybe (IO Maybe RsaKey))`. I need the PEM format and a Cryptonite.RSA key and I wrote the function `mkRsaKey` to make that from a string in PEM format.

Heres the code:

```
import qualified Crypto.PubKey.RSA as Rsa --from cryptonite
import OpenSSL.EVP.PKey -- from HsOpenSSL
import OpenSSL.PEM -- from HsOpenSSL
import OpenSSL.RSA -- from HsOpenSSL
import Prelude

data RsaKey = RsaKey
  { rsaKeyCryptoniteKey :: Rsa.PrivateKey,
    rsaKeyStringRepr :: String
  }
  deriving (Show)

openSslKeyToCryptoniteKey :: RSAKeyPair -> Maybe Rsa.PrivateKey
openSslKeyToCryptoniteKey key = do
  let d = rsaD key
  let p = rsaP key
  let q = rsaQ key
  let mdP = rsaDMP1 key
  let mdQ = rsaDMQ1 key
  let mqinv = rsaIQMP key
  let size = rsaSize key
  let n = rsaN key
  let e = rsaE key
  dP <- mdP
  dQ <- mdQ
  qinv <- mqinv

  let pub = Rsa.PublicKey size n e
  return $ Rsa.PrivateKey pub d p q dP dQ qinv

openSslKeyToRsaKey :: RSAKeyPair -> IO (Maybe RsaKey)
openSslKeyToRsaKey key = do
  stringRepr <- writePublicKey key
  let maybeCryptoKey = openSslKeyToCryptoniteKey key
  return $ do
    cryptoKey <- maybeCryptoKey
    return $ RsaKey cryptoKey stringRepr

mkRsaKey :: String -> IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe RsaKey)))
mkRsaKey privateKey = do
  someOpenSslKey <- readPrivateKey privateKey PwNone
  let openSslKey = toKeyPair someOpenSslKey
  return $ openSslKeyToRsaKey <$> openSslKey
```

Now as you can see the type signature is in my sense not optimal I would like to have `IO (Maybe RsaKey)`. How can I achieve this?

### EDIT:

I actually managed to do it but I'm using `unsafePerformIO`:

```
mkRsaKey :: String -> IO (Maybe RsaKey)
mkRsaKey privateKey = do
  someOpenSslKey <- readPrivateKey privateKey PwNone
  return $ do
    openSslKey <- toKeyPair someOpenSslKey
    unsafePerformIO (openSslKeyToRsaKey $ openSslKey)
```

As far as I know you should never use `unsafePerformIO` would there be some way to do this without it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice discovery with `case`.  This is definitely not a place where you should be using `unsafePerformIO`.  Here's a more compact way, for fun.

```
flattenMaybe :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe (m (Maybe a))) -> m (Maybe a)
flattenMaybe m = m >>= fromMaybe (return Nothing)
```

And for extra fun, the ability to flatten layers like this is a characteristic ability of monads; we're just using that ability on `m (Maybe ...)`, also known as [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html). So we could also write it like this:

```
flattenMaybe = runMaybeT . join . fmap MaybeT . MaybeT
```

Doing the necessary wrapping/unwrapping to use [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) at `MaybeT m (MaybeT m a) -> MaybeT m a`.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that if `openSslKeyToRsaKey` and `mkRsaKey` were written in terms of MaybeT to begin with, you wouldn't need `flattenMaybe` at all.

Comment: `join . fmap MaybeT = (>>= MaybeT)`

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to do it without `unsafePerformIO` the trick is to use a case statement which only uses the return function in the `Nothing` case. Here's the implementation:

```
mkRsaKey :: String -> IO (Maybe RsaKey)
mkRsaKey privateKey = do
  someOpenSslKey <- readPrivateKey privateKey PwNone
  let maybeOpenSslKey = toKeyPair someOpenSslKey
  case maybeOpenSslKey of
    Just key -> openSslKeyToRsaKey key
    Nothing -> return Nothing
```

Comment: In case you weren’t aware, the scrutinee of a case expression can itself be an expression; it doesn’t have to be a simple variable.

Comment: Also: `maybeOpenSslKey <- toKeyPair <$> readPrivateKey privateKey PwNone`.

Comment: @jlwoodwa I know but I find it more readable this way